# RubyMineでCSVをテーブル形式で編集したい

Tags: rubymine

[Editing CSV and Similar Files in Table Format](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/8.0/editing-csv-and-similar-files-in-table-format.html?search=csv)をみるとCSVをテーブル形式で編集できるようなのですができません。

具体的にいうと、Dataタブが出現しません。

Database Tools and SQLプラインは有効ですし、
拡張子が.csvのファイルはテキストとして認識するようにしています。
念のため拡張子が.csv.textも試したが同じくダメでした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSVファイルを編集する画面（エディタ）で右クリックすると

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`Edit as Table...`
が現れました。

これをクリックすると設定画面がでるので、適切に設定すると
Dataタブが出現しました。